Write rendered result back to file using xml.etree.ElementTree
Rendering and then writing result back to new xml file. I am able to do rendering but while writing back the result to xml file its not deriving the render I did.
import re
from itertools import islice

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('o211_p211_q.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def render(s, render_dict):
    groups_no = [re.compile(pattern).groups for pattern in render_dict]
    def render_func(match):
        all_groups = match.groups()
        i, j = 0, 0
        while i < len(all_groups) and all_groups[i] is None:
            i += (groups_no[j] + 1)
            j += 1
        pattern, repl = next(islice(render_dict.items(), j, j + 1))
        return re.sub(pattern, repl, all_groups[i])
    full_pattern = '|'.join(f'({pattern})' for pattern in render_dict)
    return re.sub(full_pattern, render_func, s)

def del_elements(parents, reg_exp, elem_attrib, nested=False):
    for child in reversed(parents):
        if re.match(r'{}'.format(reg_exp), child.attrib.get('{}'.format(elem_attrib))):
            parents.remove(child)
            
render_dict = {
    r'([o/p])(\d+_)[o/p](\d+_)(\w+)': r'p\2p\3\4',
    r'^(ONPREM)(_\w+)': r'CLOUD\2',
    r'^(o)(\d{1,3})' : r'a\2',
    r'^(a|p)(\d{1,3})([a-z]+)$' : r'b\2\3'
}

hvr_loc_group_members = root.findall("./hvr_loc_group_members/hvr_loc_group_member")
del_elements(hvr_loc_group_members, r'^CLOUD_SRC|^ONPREM_TGT\d+', 'grp_name', nested=True)

for chn in hvr_loc_group_members:
    for k,v in chn.attrib.items():
        chn.attrib[k] = render(v, render_dict)
    print(chn.attrib)

tree.write("rendered.xml")

In above code the print(chn.attrib) has all the result of render but when I write(tree.write) it back to file nothing is coming along of whatever modification/render I did so far.
Sample of input XML file o211_p211_q.xml -
<hvr_catalog version="1.0">
    <hvr_channels chn_name="o211_p211_q">
    </hvr_channels>
    <hvr_loc_group_members chn_name="o211_p211_q">
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="CLOUD_SRC"
            loc_name="a211"/>
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="CLOUD_TGT1"
            loc_name="p211a"/>
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="CLOUD_TGT2"
            loc_name="p211b"/>
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="ONPREM_SRC"
            loc_name="o211"/>
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="ONPREM_TGT1"
            loc_name="o211a"/>
        <hvr_loc_group_member
            chn_name="o211_p211_q"
            grp_name="ONPREM_TGT2"
            loc_name="o211b"/>
    </hvr_loc_group_members>
    <hvr_config_actions chn_name="o211_p211_q">        
    </hvr_config_actions>
</hvr_catalog>

